# Rerendering keeps the old state by default

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rendering, react-props

I have a React Typescript app that have some questions objects. When I click a button, I am shuffling existing filteredQuestions state array, but the Question components from the list rendering does not seem to rerender, because the old state is kept.

```
// App.tsx
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Question from "./Question";
import React from "react";
import { shuffleQuestions } from "./utils/utils";
import { QuestionType } from "./types/types";

const SECTION_SIZE = 20;

function App() {
    const refs = useRef<Array<React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>>>([]);
    const [scrollId, setScrollId] = useState<number>(-1);

    // Questions array is filled after a JSON file is parsed
    const [questions, setQuestions] = useState<QuestionType[]>(
        [] as QuestionType[]
    );
    const [numberOfSections, setNumberOfSections] = useState<number>(0);
    const [currentSection, setCurrentSection] = useState<number>(1);
    const [filteredQuestions, setFilteredQuestions] = useState<QuestionType[]>(
        []
    );
    const [searchQuestion, setSearchQuestion] = useState<string>("");


    useEffect(() => {
        refs.current = questions.map(() => React.createRef());
    }, [questions]);


    const handleChangeSection = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
        const sectionClicked = Number((e.target as HTMLButtonElement).value);

        if (currentSection === sectionClicked) {
            let arr = [...filteredQuestions];
            setFilteredQuestions(shuffleQuestions(arr));
        } else {
            setCurrentSection(sectionClicked);
        }
    };



    return (
        <>
            <div className='container'>
                <div
                    style={{
                        display: "flex",
                        flexDirection: "row",
                        alignItems: "center",
                        gap: "1rem",
                    }}
                >
                    <button
                        onClick={() => {
                            window.location.reload();
                        }}
                    >
                        Reset all
                    </button>
                    <label htmlFor='avatar'>
                        Choose a JSON file containig questions:
                    </label>
                    <input
                        type='file'
                        id='avatar'
                        name='avatar'
                        accept='application/JSON'
                        onChange={handleUploadFile}
                    />
                </div>

                <div style={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
                    {Array.from({ length: numberOfSections }, (_, index) => (
                        <button onClick={handleChangeSection} key={index} value={index + 1}>
                            {index * SECTION_SIZE +
                                1 +
                                "-" +
                                Math.min(questions.length, (index + 1) * SECTION_SIZE)}
                        </button>
                    ))}
                </div>


                { filteredQuestions.map((question, index) => (
                            <div ref={refs.current[index]} key={question.id}>
                                <Question
                                    question={question}
                                    setScrollId={setScrollId}
                                    originalId={question.id}
                                    randomIdx={index}
                                />
                            </div>
                      ))
                }
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

```
// Question.tsx

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { QuestionType, ChoiceType } from "./types/types";

enum AnsweredQuestionState {
    CORRECT = "CORRECT",
    WRONG = "WRONG",
}

type AnsweredQuestion = {
    state: AnsweredQuestionState | null;
};

type QuestionProps = {
    question: QuestionType;
    setScrollId: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>;
    originalId: number;
    randomIdx: number;
};

export default function Question(props: QuestionProps) {
    const { question, setScrollId, originalId, randomIdx } = props;

    // If, for example, the new state is AnsweredQuestion.CORRECT, it still stays
    // the same, even though randomIdx have changed, for example. So the props
    // have changed, but the state is still the same

    
    const [selectedAnswer, setSelectedAnswer] = useState<AnsweredQuestion>({
        state: null,
    });

    const getQuestionStateStyle = (
        questionChoice: ChoiceType,
        choiceIdx: number
    ) => {
        if (choiceIdx == 0) {
            console.log(
                "Checking styles for question" + question.quest + " with randomIdx:",
                randomIdx
            );

            console.log(`Question ${question.quest} rendered`);
            console.log(selectedAnswer);
        }

        if (selectedAnswer.state) {
            if (questionChoice.isCorrect) {
                return "green";
            }

            if (selectedAnswer.state === AnsweredQuestionState.WRONG) {
                if (questionChoice.isCorrect === undefined) {
                    return "red";
                }
            }
        }
    };

    const handleAnswerClick = (choice: ChoiceType) => {
        setSelectedAnswer((prevSelectedAnswer) => {
            const state = choice.isCorrect
                ? AnsweredQuestionState.CORRECT
                : AnsweredQuestionState.WRONG;
            return { ...prevSelectedAnswer, state };
        });
    };


    return (
        <div className='question-container'>
            <h4>
                {originalId + 1}. {question.quest}
            </h4>
            {question.choices.map((questionChoice, idx) => (
                <div
                    className={`question ` + getQuestionStateStyle(questionChoice, idx)}
                    onClick={() => handleAnswerClick(questionChoice)}
                    key={idx}
                >
                    {questionChoice.str}
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

```
export type QuestionDefault = {
    quest: string;
    choices: ChoiceType[]
}
export type QuestionType = QuestionDefault & {
    id: number;
}
```

**Expected**: Each Question component from the list rendering will rerender because filteredQuestions variable have changed (due to randomization, even the randomIdx would be probably modified), so that the oldState shouldn't be kept in the Question component.

**Behavior**: Question components does seem to update the props, but the old state (**selectedAnswer**) is kept as well. If I print the randomIdx, it does print the correct one if this prop has changed, but selectedAnswer remains the same as before (the choices have the same style applied as before)

Comment: Please show the function `shuffleQuestions`.

Comment: You never set `numberOfSections` to anything other than 0, so by this example nothing would appear.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
        <div style={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
            {Array.from({ length: numberOfSections }, (_, index) => (
                <button onClick={handleChangeSection} key={index} value={index + 1}>
                    {index * SECTION_SIZE +
                        1 +
                        "-" +
                        Math.min(questions.length, (index + 1) * SECTION_SIZE)}
                </button>
            ))}
        </div>
```

The number of elements you are showing is equal to `numberOfSections`. But `numberOfSections` is always `0`. You don't need `numberOfSections`. You can remove it.

Rewrite this HTML to map the questions array. Do yourself a favour and pass the index directly to `handleChangeSection` too.

```
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
          {questions.map((_, index) => (
            <button onClick={() => handleChangeSection(index + 1)} key={index}>
              {index * SECTION_SIZE +
                1 +
                '-' +
                Math.min(questions.length, (index + 1) * SECTION_SIZE)}
            </button>
          ))}
        </div>
```

Then `handleChangeSection` would be:

```
  const handleChangeSection = (sectionClicked: number) => {
    if (currentSection === sectionClicked) {
      let arr = [...filteredQuestions];
      setFilteredQuestions(arr);
    } else {
      setCurrentSection(sectionClicked);
    }
  };
```

Comment: actually, I am updating the number of sections when the questions are fetched. I did not included the update because it wasn't the point of my problem, but I have this useEffect:

`useEffect(() => {
  setNumberOfSections(Math.floor(questions.length / SECTION_SIZE) + 1);
 }, [questions]);`

Comment: also, the shuffle function is this:
`function shuffleQuestions(array: QuestionType[]) {
    let newArr = [...array];
    newArr.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
    return newArr;
  }`